# Is the image of Spec$k$ closed under these conditions?

Tags: schemes, finitely-generated

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $\phi:\textrm{Spec}\ k\longrightarrow X$ be a morphism of schemes of finite type. Let us denote the only point of $\textrm{Spec }k$ by $\zeta$, and the image of $\zeta$ under $\phi$ be $x$, i.e., $\phi(\zeta)=x$. I want to prove that $x$ is a closed point in $X$.

I know that $x$ is closed point iff $k\subset k(x)$ is a finite extension, where $k(x)$ is the residue field at $x$. So by Zariski's lemma, it is enough to prove that $k(x)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. But how do I prove this? I am guessing that this is a consequence of $\phi$ being a morphism of finite type. But I am not able to get a proof. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: That $\phi$ be of finite type means, in particular, that locally it is given by a morphism of rings of finite type. So reduce to affine opens where this is true... and what can you de then?

Comment: Dear poorna, Is this an exercise from somewhere (in which case, could you possibly have omitted some assumptions)?  The reason I ask is that it's not true in general that a finite type morphism from Spec of a field to a general scheme need have closed image.  Regards,

Comment: I have been asked to prove that $k$ valued points of schemes of finite type over $k$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field, can be identified with closed points of $X$. I thought it reduces to this.